# How Do We Promote This Site?

Tags: discussion

What are some ideas and suggestions for promoting this site and encouraging experts to post questions and answers?

The Stack Exchange Blog mentions [Sharing Links to Questions to Earn The Announcer, Booster, and Publicist Badges](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/announcer-booster-and-publicist-badges/), but what else can we do to effectively promote the site?

Since the Motor Vehicle Maintenance and Repair topic is not about a computer-related field, are there any special differences between promoting this site and promoting a site like Programmers SE, Project Management SE, or Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 3):

There's some additional advice here

http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/a-recipe-to-promote-your-site/

But of course, it always starts with sharing links to great questions and great answers!